# How exactly does setvbuf fill the buffer?

Tags: c, io, buffer

I have some questions for better understanding of the usage of setvbuf:

I want to read a line from a file into a buffer and then read/parse it at will. The problem is, how to get the line. I was under the impression that *_IOLBF* makes setvbuf read from the stream line by line. From the C99 ISO i understand that a call to setvbuf just assigns a (or none) buffer to a stream but doesn't operate on it yet.

So I imagine that if I read from the stream afterwards it should fill the buffer first and then execute the operation (read in this case) from this buffer. Is that correct? If no: how does it exactly work?

Here is a small example. My expectation is that once I call fread the buffer *buffer* will be filled with characters until either *\n* or the given size is reached. Then I thought to get the line (or number of characters) out of that buffer with printf.
It **almost** works how I explain it except for the need of "correct" size arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 64

int main()
{
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    char buffer2[BUF_SIZE];
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("file.dat", "r");
    setvbuf(fp, buffer, _IOLBF, 64);
    fread(buffer2, 1, 32, fp);
    printf("buffer:\n%s\n", buffer);
    printf("buffer2:\n%s\n", buffer2);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

What bugs me is that I read

> You shouldn’t try to access the values in the array directly while the stream is using it for buffering.

As said in this link: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html

Why is that?

At last I read here:
http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/c_von_a_bis_z/016_c_ein_ausgabe_funktionen_020.htm
(Although this is in german, everything needed to understand this is provided in my question.)

That the lines:

```
setvbuf(src, NULL, _IOLBF, 80);
setvbuf(dest, NULL, _IOLBF, 80);
```

copy 80 characters from src to dest, which I tested with my file stream and stdout in hope that I could see output on my terminal. Which did not work. Why?

Comment: `setvbuf()` doesn't read anything.  It allocates space to be used by the file stream.  That's all.  You should not poke at the buffer after you hand it over to the stream — it is for the library to use, not you.  You have no knowledge of what it does with it.  The stream being line buffered applies mostly to output — it means the data will be flushed if there is a newline in the message.

Comment: `setvbuf` does not (and cannot) change how the stream is read based on the content.  It just controls the timing and the size of operations when IO happens between the internal buffers and the stream.  If you set the block size to 80, then reads will read 80 bytes at a time.  Making the stream line buffered means that if you `fwrite` or `putc` a newline, then a write will occur on the stream.

Comment: Also note that you should use `setvbuf()` once only per stream.  And you must call `setvbuf()` before you do any I/O operations on the stream.

Comment: Accessing the buffer is [explicitly undefined behavior](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2): "An attempt is made to use the contents of the array that was supplied in a call to the `setvbuf` function"

Comment: POSIX has a `getline` function that reads a whole line from a stdio stream. If an implementation's C runtime library does not have `getline`, it is not _too_ difficult to write an equivalent function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really depend on this in any useful way. The specification describes the different buffering modes in vague, general ways, because different environments and types of streams have restrictions on the ways that I/O can be performed.

In the [Files](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p3) section of the specification it says:

> When a stream is unbuffered, characters are intended to appear from the source or at the destination as soon as possible. Otherwise characters may be accumulated and transmitted to or from the host environment as a block. When a stream is fully buffered, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a buffer is filled. When a stream is line buffered, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line character is encountered. Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to the host environment when a buffer is filled, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of characters from the host environment. **Support for these characteristics is implementation-defined, and may be affected via the setbuf and setvbuf functions.**

And in the description of [setvbuf](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.6p2) itself it says:

> The argument mode determines how stream will be buffered, as follows: _IOFBF causes input/output to be fully buffered; _IOLBF causes input/output to be line buffered; _IONBF causes input/output to be unbuffered. If buf is not a null pointer, the array it points to may be used instead of a buffer allocated by the setvbuf function273) and the argument size specifies the size of the array; otherwise, size may determine the size of a buffer allocated by the setvbuf function. **The contents of the array at any time are indeterminate.**